# MySQL - compare two fields and return match in percents

Tags: mysql, compare

Currently we have a website which is storing a user added text as type mediumtext.

Currently our system is checking the text for match and return true(yes it matches) when it is 1:1 (100% same - one space and it will be taken as new text).

We are trying to make system smarter. It must be possible to tell us in percents how much the contents are same (in percents). Unfortunately we don't have good progress. Almost every algorithm we was able to think of was not working correctly or it was VERY slow and heavy.

We are hoping someone will be able to give us a boost.

*Note: we was trying to make a byte compare but things did not work properly.*

EDIT: We are not limited to MySQL only. We was looking in apache solr server. If it have advantages please give help in this direction or event something better if have.

Comment: Have you looked at [full-text search?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Yes, but not satisfied. Do you have some ideas for matching the content in percents?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the Levenshtein distance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Example on SO:
[MySQL Levenshtein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617348/mysql-levenshtein)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN( s1 CHAR(255), s2 CHAR(255)) 
RETURNS int(3) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR(255);
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 CHAR(255);

    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1);
    SET s2_len = LENGTH(s2);
    SET cv1 = 0x00;
    SET j = 1;
    SET i = 1;
    SET c = 0;

    IF s1 = s2 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE IF s1_len = 0 THEN
        RETURN s2_len;
    ELSE IF s2_len = 0 THEN
        RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
                SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
                IF c > c_temp THEN
                    SET c = c_temp;
                END IF;
                SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hello. Can you give me more help since mysql is returning error:

for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
END' at line 36

Comment: sorry, not my code. You can google for other mysql implementations. My answer is just to put you on the right track, not to give a complete solution.

Comment: I fixed it and it is very very very slow for the purpose we need it. Result: Showing rows 10 - 9 ( 10 total, Query took 232.2726 sec)