# Select value from database with php where condition value is similar to input

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering....is it possible to retrieve a value from a mysql database if the value of the WHERE statement is similar to the input text? Something like the similar_text() function but applied to the search condition.

Example:

```
 <?php
   $res = mysqli_query(*CONECTION*,"SELECT value FROM table WHERE condition=*is similar to x*");
  ?>
```

If this thing is possible please tell me how.

Comment: Use [`LIKE`](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-like-in-operators.htm) --- [`full-text indexes`](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/18) could also be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make use of the **`LIKE`** keyword

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE condition like %x%
```

**EDIT :**

Seems like you are for levenshtein algorithm. Have a look [here](http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/mysql-levenshtein/) and [here](http://blog.cavar.si/2011/04/how-to-implement-levenshtein-algotithm.html).
[`StackOverflow Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql)

Comment: can i specify how similar should the 2 values be?

Comment: `LIKE` does not test similarity. From the docs: "Pattern matching using SQL simple regular expression comparison"

Comment: Or `like %x` or `like x%` ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will do the rest of the research on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value, MATCH(value) AGAINST('x' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS similarIndex
FROM table WHERE MATCH(value) AGAINST ('x' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY similarIndex DESC
```