# Calculate similarity between to records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to figure out how to calculate the similarity between two records. My first record would be from a deactivated advertisement - so I want to find e.g. the 10 most similar advertisement regarding to some VARCHAR-fields equalness.

The thing, I can't figure out is, if there is any MySQL function, that can help me in any way - or if I need to compare the strings in some weird way?

### EDIT #1

Similarity would be defined by these fields:

- Title (weight: 50 %)
- Content (weight: 40 %)
- Category (weight: 10 %)

### EDIT #2

I want the calculation to be like this:

Title: Words that match in the title field (only words >2 letters are matched).

Description: Words that match in the title field (only words >2 letters are matched).

Catgory: Match the category and if that doesn't match match the parent category with less weight :)

An equation of this could be:

> #1 is the old, inactive post, #2 is the active post:
>
> #2 title matches #1 title in 3 words out of #2's total of 10 words.
>   That gives 30 % match = 30 points.
>
> #2 description matches #1 description in 10 words out of #2's total
>   of 400 words. That gives a 4 % match = 4 points.
>
> #2 category doesn't match #1's category, therefore 0 % match. That
>   gives 0 points.
>
> Then the sum would be 34 points for #2. :)

### Edit #3

Here's my query - but it doesn't return different rows, but a lot of the same row.

```
SELECT
            a.AdvertisementID as A_AdvertisementID,
            IF(a.Topic LIKE a2.Topic, 50, 0) + IF(a.Description LIKE a2.Description, 40, 0) + IF(a.Cate_CategoryID LIKE a2.Cate_CategoryID, 10, 0) as A_Score,
            a.AdvertisementID as A_AdvertisementID,
            a.Topic as A_Topic,
            LEFT(a.Description, 300) as A_Description,
            a.Price as A_Price,
            a.Type as A_Type
        FROM
            ".DB_PREFIX."A_Advertisements a2,
            ".DB_PREFIX."A_Advertisements a
        WHERE
            a2.AdvertisementID <> a.AdvertisementID
            AND
            a.AdvertisementID = :a_id
        ORDER BY
            A_Score DESC
```

Comment: How are you defining "similarity"?

Comment: Hey Rowland Shaw - I have tried to define it in my latest edit. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

Comment: Are you looking for equality in those fields? Or do you have some idea of how to calculate a metric of "how similar" two strings are?

Comment: Rowland: Nah, but I think, I want to match words. In the total advanced query, I would have the possibility to not give any value to 0-2 letter words, but match the rest. Then I want to take the  sum of the matches and add the weight in percentages. I'll add a calculation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can literally compare the fields you are interested in, you could have MySQL perform a simple scoring calculation using the [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, for example

```
select 
  foo.id,
  if (foo.title='wantedtitle', 50, 0) +
  if (foo.content='wantedcontent', 40, 0) +
  if (foo.category='wantedcategory', 10, 0) as score
from foo
order by score desc
limit 10
```

A basic 'find a fragment' could be achieved using like

```
select 
  foo.id,
  if (foo.title like '%wantedtitlefragment%', 50, 0) +
  if (foo.content like '%wantedcontentfragment%', 40, 0) +
  if (foo.category like '%wantedcategoryfragment%', 10, 0) as score
from foo
order by score desc
limit 10
```

There are other techniques, but they might be slow to implement in MySQL. For example, you could calculate the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two string - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql) for an example implementation.

Comment: Could I use LIKE instead of equal sign? :)

Comment: Yes, that would work just fine for a basic wildcard.

Comment: Okay, now my problem is, that I only know the OLD advertisements URL. How can I join so it will get the 10 with highest "score"? :)

Comment: Hey Paul, I've changed my question - can you help on edit #3? :)

Comment: Make sure you index the columns, especially when using '%...%' searches (in this case, only FULLTEXT indexes will be useful). Also, I don't think it's fair that you keep added more and more requests on top of your original question... that isn't how SO works.

Comment: Terry: Okay, that's my mistake. :)