# How can I find similar records in the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a scheduling database, and I would like to find a way to select all future appointments that are similar because we have a lot of clients who double book themselves.  I have been looking but I cant find a way to do quite what I want.

For example if I have the following rows I would like to be able to select those with the same language, a time within 15 minutes of each other, and with names that share > 70% of the same characters.

```
   |Rec_id|Date_time       |Language|App_name |
   |1     |2014-03-15 12:40|Spanish |Ricardo  |
   |2     |2014-03-15 12:45|Spanish |Ricerdu  |
   |3     |2014-03-16 12:45|Tongan  |Tuaffu   |
   |4     |2014-03-17 12:45|Korean  |Kim      |
   |5     |2014-03-18 12:45|German  |Biternof |
   |6     |2014-03-18 12:32|German  |Biterknof|
```

From the above data the records I would need are 1,2,5, and 6.

Comment: they are not duplicate , they are different app_name ?

Comment: They are not duplicate, but our clients dont want to pay when we schedule 2 staff to be available.  This happens on a much much larger scale several times a day.

Comment: I would also love to know the reason for the down votes.  Is there a way I could improve this question?

Comment: No way I could think of, and I don't understand the downvotes either. There I up you a bit, sorry about those bad votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I thought of was Levenshtein but since MySQL has no native support for it - things get little more complex.

This solution isn't optimized or the best solution at all, but I should do the work.

- I would create a new column, let's call it "Duplicate_for", DEFAULT NULL.
- I would create a trigger: TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT for this table.
- I would create a function to calculate the Levenshtein distance for two strings.
- I would combine TRIGGER and Levenshtein with following query.

Trigger + query itself:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `booking_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `booking` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE existingId INT(10) DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT 
        MAX(id) 
    INTO 
        existingId
    FROM 
        booking 
    WHERE   
        booking.dirty_id IS NULL AND
        booking.lang = NEW.lang AND
        booking.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND 
        (LEVENSHTEIN(booking.name, NEW.name) / LENGTH(booking.name)) < 0.3;

    SET NEW.dirty_id = existingId;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You can read more about Levenshtein from:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
- http://openquery.com.au/blog/levenshtein-mysql-stored-function
- [How to add levenshtein function in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql)

Now you can detect the duplicates with Duplicate_for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have the Levenshtien set up, but I am having some problems with the trigger.  How do I declare the existingID in a trigger?

Comment: Added the code for trigger. `booking` is the name of table.

Comment: Thank you @niko-hujanen, for some reason the Levenshtien does not seem to be working though.  I am still playing with it.  I have verified the stored procedure works, but I seem to get a duplicate flag regardless of what the new name is.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I need to dencrypt the name.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice question.. Kept me awake for a long time at Night.. :D :D
First of all, you don't need any triggers and/or extra rows for solving this.

This is what I have attempted so far.

```
SELECT
t3.*
FROM
Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
Table1 t2
ON
(
  t2.Rec_id > t1.Rec_id
  AND t2.Language = t1.Language
  AND ABS( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.Date_time, t2.Date_time)) <= 15
  #AND (
  #  SOUNDEX( t1.App_name ) LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM SOUNDEX( t2.App_name )), '%') 
  #  OR
  #  SOUNDEX( t2.App_name ) LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM SOUNDEX( t1.App_name )), '%')
  #)
)
INNER JOIN
Table1 t3
ON( t1.Rec_id = t3.Rec_id OR t2.Rec_id = t3.Rec_id )
GROUP BY t3.Rec_id
```

I have commented out the `SOUNDEX` part.. 70% match is something fuzzy, isn't it.. 
Try uncommenting the `SOUNDEX` part of the query to check if it solves the larger problem.