# how do I search substring in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in my database table :

```
-------------------------------
name            | address
-------------------------------
raj kumar       | park street    
yogin patel     | ghari chowk 
raju singh      | sultan ganj
```

I would like to retrieve a row containing `sultan ganj`, but by mistake I search for `sultanganj` (*no space between words*). What query will I use in order to get the correct result?

Comment: combine `replace`, and `like` in `where` clause. Example: `select * from table_name where replace( address, ' ', '' ) like '%sultanganj%';`

Comment: Look into Levenshtein distance if you're doing some sort of search function

Comment: MySQL does not contain a Levenshtein function, but there is an implementation listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql This is better, imho, that the answers involving replacing spaces, at it will help with more general mispellings.

Answer (score 1):

You can `REPLACE` all spaces  in the field `address` with empty strings and compare them with `sultanganj`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE REPLACE(`address`, ' ', '') = 'sultanganj'
```

This will return you :

```
-------------------------
    name   |   address
-------------------------
raju singh | sultan ganj
```

Comment: thanks for answer but there is one more problem suppose I searched for parkroad(no space between the word) and there is no such word in my database but still I want to recieve  rows either containing park or road or both.Then which query will I use ? plz answer

Answer (score 1):

Just do like below using `REPLACE` function to replace the extra space in value

```
select name, address
from yourtable
where replace(address,' ','') = 'sultanganj'
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the same query in answer except that change the `WHERE` condition to be like where address like '%park%' or address like '%road%'. This way it will match all address which contains either the word `park` or `road` or `both` (example: `parkroad`,`parkstreet`,`HellRoad`,`Heavenpark` etc).

```
select name, address
from yourtable
where address like '%park%' or address like '%road%'
```

Comment: thanks for answer  but there is one more problem suppose I searched for parkroad(no space between the word) and there is no such word in my database but still I want to recieve a row either containing park or road or both.Then which query will I use ? plz answer

Comment: @user3717804, you can use the same query in answer except that change the `WHERE` condition to be like `where address like '%park%' or address like '%road%'`.

Comment: which query  you used to break single word(parkroad) into two word (park,road)?

Answer (score 0):

Below query will help you

```
select * from table1 Where replace(address,' ','') = replace('sultanganj',' ','')
```

Comment: thanks for answer but there is one more problem suppose I searched for parkroad(no space between the word) and there is no such word in my database but still I want to recieve a row either containing park or road or both.Then which query will I use ? plz answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table where replace(`address`,' ', '' ) like '%your search element%' or `address` like '%your search element%'
```

and this query working for me

Edit

```
(1)SELECT * FROM table where replace(`address`,' ', '' ) like '%parkstreet%' or `address` like '%parkstreet%'
(2)SELECT * FROM table where replace(`address`,' ', '' ) like '%park%' or `address` like '%park%'
(3)SELECT * FROM table where replace(`address`,' ', '' ) like '%street%' or `address` like '%street%'
(4)SELECT * FROM table where replace(`address`,' ', '' ) like '%park street%' or `address` like '%park street%'
```

Comment: thanks for answer but there is one more problem suppose I searched for parkroad(no space between the word) and there is no such word in my database but still I want to recieve a row either containing park or road or both.Then which query will I use ? plz answer

Comment: @user3717804 you can use the same query in this answer

Comment: @user3717804 i edit the answer and also check this query for search element "park" ,"road","parkroad" and "park road" and it working for me..

Comment: tell me query how did you break the word parkroad into park,road

Comment: ok basically I think u did not get my question so let me clarify it for you.so i am searching for "parkroad" and in my database if u see above there is no such word but there is "park street".so instead of getting no result what i want is to recieve the rows containing park or road. I m not giving input again and again .I have given the input once "parkstreet".so now you give the query how you broke parkstreet into two words park,street