# How to compare every record to another record(name reverse problem) and erase duplicates one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a terrible to identify unique record(value).
I have a table like this:

```
ID NAME            DESCRIPTION
1  Yanagida Fumit  best author
2  Ha Il-kwan      new author
3  Fumit Yanagida  best author
4  Ha Il Kwan      new author
5  Ilkwan Ha       new author
```

There are 5 records in same table called `autho` table. But in actually, there are 2 authors.
First record and third record are stored from one author information and second, 4th and 5th are one author.
I want to make this like below.

```
ID NAME            DESCRIPTION
1  Yanagida Fumit  best author
2  Ha Il Kwan      new author
```

It means that, I am going to erase all duplicates against **reverse name problem**.
I wonder if I can compare two values(string) in same column.
Help me please. I will be happy with your any help!

Comment: You want to use levenshtein distance to resolve this.

Comment: Convert to SET, where each bit is a presence of definite letter. This is enough to identify >95% of duplicates.

Comment: @Mech Thanks for your quick answer!
Would you mind explain further more detail about levenshtein distance?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107101/mysql-using-levenshtein-distance-to-find-duplicates-in-20-000-rows

Comment: Levenshtein is not applicable - the distance between 'Ha Il Kwan' and 'Ilkwan Ha' won't give to identify that they're duplicates.

Comment: I have found a similar solution here on stack but I think I am not using it correct :) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f10c70f08222a170eb5993c515975a7d

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am very happy for your help.  I face levenshtein first time. So I surprise with every answer (especially @VBoka 's answer).   :)

Comment: Are you looking to do this solely through mysql or do you want to run a php script?

Comment: @Mech  I want to solve this problem using only sql query.
I might use php script but I think it 's better I use only sql.

Comment: @Mech so do you have any solution with php script?

Comment: Having a look at what I can do for you in mysql. Are you looking to specify the terms of the deletion? ie search for "Yanagida Fumit" and delete the rest?

Comment: @Mech Yes you are right. it has a bit more conditions but I will resolve them myself.
Main point is to remove rest after searching.

Comment: building a solution now.

Comment: .... so what happens if you have two actual authors with "mirrored" names; `Frank Ben` and `Ben Frank`

Comment: That's exactly what the provided example is. MATCH AGAINST will find the data, regardless of order.

Comment: Your table has three different version of the name for "Ha Il Kwan" -- what logic could  the code employ to find the one you like best?   At a loss to understand how you chose.

Comment: @CharlieK I will prefer  "Ha Il Kwan". Anyway thanks for your considering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php solution:

```
remove_duplicates("Yanagida Fumit");

function remove_duplicates($full_search_str) {        
    // establish connection to your db

    // fetch data
    $query = "          SELECT  `id`, `name` 
                        FROM    `" . $tbl_name . "`
                        WHERE   MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('" . $full_search_str . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                        AND     `name` <> '" . $full_search_str . "'
             ";

    // run query
    $results = $conn->query($query);

    // loop through results
    foreach($results as $result) {
            // build query
            $query = "  DELETE 
                        FROM    `" . $tbl_name . "`
                        WHERE   `id` = " . $result['id'];

            // run query
            $result = $conn->query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... the PHP is not relevant.  Furthermore, it's potentially dangerous due to the unnecessary dynamic SQL (and lack of a prepared statement).  Oh, and it would remove **all** instances of a given name, which isn't at all desired.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle answer:

create or replace table authors as
Select distinct name, description
from authors;

Comment: ....not sufficient; the data as presented is _already_ distinct (although this may remove some entries).

Comment: On first read, I didn't see that you have records with data misplaced between fields in a single record as well as inconsistent data for a single field, consequently you're left with questions as to the correct record between:
first name       last name
Ha                   Il Kwan
Il Kwan            Ha
Ha                    Il-Kwan   

This isn't a SQL uniqueness problem -- it's a data corruption problem that is best solved by controlling what gets into the data at the start.