# PHP Search without entire word/name or misspelt word/name

Tags: php, search

I have made a search function for finding staff members based on a first name search, here is the code for that.

**search.php**

```
<?php
include ('connect-db.php');
if (isset($_GET ['forename'])){
$forename = $_GET['forename'];

$forename_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $forename);
$userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename = '$forename_escaped'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($userquery) == null ) echo ('NO RESULTS FOUND IN DATABASE');{
    ?>
```

But what I would like this function to do is to return results even when in the search box the first name was misspelt by a letter or only partially entered.

*e.g. User input - Search: Jennif -->[SEARCH FUNCTION] Returns results for 'Jennifer' OR User input - Search: Jjennifer --> [SEARCH FUNCTION] Returns results for 'Jennifer'*

How could I perform an operation like this? I was thinking of using a **'LIKE'** function but so far haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Glad you mentioned that actually I was just going through my pages a couple weeks ago adding parameters and completely forgot about this one.

Answer (score 4):

You want to find the difference between strings, also known as Levenshtein Distance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

For a implementation into mysql you might want to concider following post:

[How to add levenshtein function in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql)

Taken the Levenshtein implementation within the linked page your query should look like this:

```
$userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE levenshtein(forename, '".$forename_escaped."') < 2");
```

This means the levenshtein distance is lower then 2.

Comment: Okay, I've read up on Levenshtein distance and had a look over the other SO post about it you shared, My next question, How can that be executed in php within the current search function?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, last question though (I promise) I still don't see how/where I can add that code from the other link

Comment: You just need to copy and paste the code and execute it on your mysql server once. This way you add a function to mysql server. For more information on that you might want to read the documentation for stored procedures...
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Levenshtein is an expensive algorithm to run across a large number of records, so you will need to find a way to reduce the number of records you search for misspellings (e.g. pre-filter by dept).    If performance becomes an issue you'll need to read up on [Levenshtein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata) (data structures for solving this problem efficiently — requires preindexing)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting a similar function to this with their search:

I used a **Wildcard** to allow the search to get results without an entire name typed in. here's what it looks like:

```
$userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename LIKE '$forename_escaped%'");
```

Hope this helps people in the future.