# MYSQLI Query ORDER by most amount of matching characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a search function on my project utilizing `mysqli` LIKE query.

My final hurdle is the `ORDER` in which it outputs.

Current Scenario:

```
if(isset($_GET['userInput']))
{
$search = $_GET['userInput'];
$search = explode(" ", $search);
if($search[0] != ''){
    $firstterm = $search[0];
}else{
    $firstterm = '@@@';
}
if($search[1] != ''){
    $secondterm = $search[1];
}else{
    $secondterm = '@@@';
}}

$contact = $mysqli->query("
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE 
f_name LIKE '%$firstterm%'
OR l_name LIKE '%$firstterm%'

OR f_name LIKE '%$secondterm%'
OR l_name LIKE '%$secondterm%'

order by id LIMIT 5");
```

My question is, is there a way to `ORDER` by the most amount of matching characters as apposed to `id`. The reason being if I type 'C Blogs' looking for 'Craig Blogs' the 'C' will register a hit on everyone of my contacts because of the email address '.[c]om'.

So if I can get it to ORDER by most amount of matching characters (the added amount from both explodes where there is more than 1) the top result should theoretically be 'Craig Blogs'.

Comment: I suggest you sort the results in PHP, using the `levenshtein` function to compare the search terms.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for this suggestion, I will look in to it. If you could point me in the direction of it being used as an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No idea where to find examples. That's what search engines are for. Basically, you just want to use `usort`, and write a comparison function that compares `levenshtein($a)` with `levenshtein($b)`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the extra effort. When I have a working solution should I post it as the answer or could I somehow set your comment as the answer at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of matches using `+`.  In MySQL, a boolean expression is treated as a number with 1 being true and 0 being 1:

```
ORDER BY ((f_name LIKE '%$firstterm%') +
          (l_name LIKE '%$firstterm%') +
          (f_name LIKE '%$secondterm%') +
          (l_name LIKE '%$secondterm%')
         ) desc
```

EDIT:

If you want the number of matching characters, you can start with the length of the search terms.  However, terms could appear more than once.  So:

```
ORDER BY ((length(replace(f_name, 'firstterm', concat('firstterm', 'x'))) - length(f_name)) +
          (length(replace(l_name, 'firstterm', concat('firstterm', 'x'))) - length(l_name)) +
          (length(replace(f_name, 'secondterm', concat('secondterm', 'x'))) - length(f_name)) +
          (length(replace(l_name, 'secondterm', concat('secondterm', 'x'))) - length(l_name))
         ) desc
```

Comment: That's the number of terms that matches, not the number of characters that match.

Comment: @Barmar correct. It is still matching 2x terms (including the email '.com') and therefore c blogs still means it is ordering by id.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff This is still not working it seems to be doing the same thing as your original submission.

Comment: @Bjaeg . . . No.  It should be counting the number of appearances of each term in each field and adding them together.  That is the number of matching characters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tried your submission, I have tried changing it to the '$' infront of firstterm and secondterm I have tried it as this; '%$firstterm%', '%$secondterm%' etc. Am I supposed to replace the 'x' with something?

Comment: @Bjaeg . . . No.  Anything with one character should work.  This construct counts the number of times that each term occurs in each of the fields.