# How to search in a mysql database the fields that contains the letters from a string

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help. I want to search in a database the letters that I pass. For example, if I enter the word "steve", the query must look for all the names that contains the letters 'stve'. I tried with:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'steve%'  or name like '%steve'  or name like '%steve%'";
```

But it doesn't do what I want because it looks for the pattern.  The same happens with:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(`name`, 'steve') > 0";
```

Could you help me please.

Comment: To search for individual letters from the word, you should use regular expression using `RLIKE`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be case problem??How if you use the following query.

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(name) LIKE 'steve%'  or lower(name) like '%steve'  or lower(name) like '%steve%'";
```

Make sure your steve also  lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [MYSQL search for right words | fixing spelling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212058/mysql-search-for-right-words-fixing-spelling-errors)

You can use `SOUNDEX` or `SOUNDS LIKE` but that is costly and may not be what you want. Maybe you can return all the rows and parse with a levestien(sp) shift if you are using PHP?