# PHP search function, for searching DB with non exact search term

Tags: php, sql, search

I have created a search function on my site that searches my DB using `LIKE` as shown here:

```
$term = $_GET['search'];
$newterm = '%'.$term.'%';

$params = [$newterm];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
```

However, this isn't great for misspellings or additional characters.

So for example, if my DB contains: [blue hat, red hat, black hat, white hat].
If I search for hat, all the results come back as expected.
If I search for hats, I get no results.
If I search for hta, I get no results.

Is there a better way to search the DB for similar results or have a warning like Google that says something like this based on what actually is in the DB:

```
You searched for hta, did you mean hat?
```

Comment: You probably want a combination of full-text searching and a database of common misspellings (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aLists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines)

Comment: [Natural Language Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) with FULLTEXT indexes or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) choose your poison.

Comment: Maybe this thread is useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212058/mysql-search-for-right-words-fixing-spelling-errors

Comment: What you are looking for is call the `levenshtein` method.  IT's really intensive and will dog MySQL down pretty good.  At that point you might think about a third party indexing tool like `SOLR`.  It basically indexes your MySQL and creates XML files --  It makes for faster searches and a much better version of the `levenshtein` type search.