# Implementing smiliar_text or Levenshtein query

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

im trying to query a smarter search result, i checked online about Leveshtein and similiar_text but i believe Leveshtein algorithm is the best optionm how could i implement in my query the algorithm of LEvenshtein? I cant find any good resource on magento or even using this function on the attributeSelect, here is my initial code.

```
function queryBuy($string){
    $items = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToFilter(array(
                        array('attribute'=>'name','like'=> "%".$string."%"),
    ));
```

Should i make in Raw SQL? Does magento have any method available where i could use it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
$items = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name',
                        array('like'=> "% ".$string." %") //spaces on each side
    );
```

you can also check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11084/20064)

Answer (score 0):

You can change any part of collection query with

```
$collection->getSelect()
```

**Example**

```
$collection->getSelect()->where("some field LIKE %expression%"
```