# MySQL query to find similar values in a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, similarity

I have duplicate entries that are highly similar, but not exact. Here are some examples:

```
- 2016: Obama's America
- 2016: Obama's America (VF)

- Hurt Locker
- The Hurt Locker
```

What would be a query that I could use to get potentially similar `titles` ?

### Update

Please note that I am not trying to remove EXACT duplicates. I am only trying to select similar values in a single column.

Comment: Good question! Maybe something with [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)?

Comment: I think that's half the problem.  If defining "similar" was easy, this question would barely be worth asking.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the best way or most efficient, and it definitely depends on the meaning of similar.  If the meaning is the title contains all of the text in one row but some of the text in another row, then something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Title
FROM YourTable T
   LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T.Title != T2.Title
WHERE T.Title LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.Title, '%')
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Title
FROM YourTable T
   LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T.Title != T2.Title
WHERE T.Title LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.Title, '%')
ORDER BY Title
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f439/1).

Comment: I don't think this will do. The movie [America](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670931/) would match all movies with America in it.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels -- yeah, like I said, similar is very vague :)  Interesting question nonetheless.  I'd like to ask you -- what should America match?  Only movies like America One, but not America The Great :)  Best of luck.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels -- one option would be to add a maximum length difference -- here's a quick fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17173/1

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be solved by measuring the distance between strings with some [string metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric).

Levenshtein seems to be the most well known metric and I have used some implementation of it in Oracle. It is [implemented for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617348/mysql-levenshtein) also. You might find some other metric that will work better for you.