# Levenshtein search

Tags: php, mysql, levenshtein-distance

I work on a site which sells let's say *stuff* and offers a "vendors search". On this search you enter your city, or postal code, or region and a distance (in km or miles) then the site gives you a list of vendors.

To do that, I have a database with the vendors. In the form to save these vendors, you enter their full address and when you click on the save button, a request to google maps is made in order to get their latitude and longitude.

When someone does a search, I look on a table where I store all the search terms and their lat/lng.
This table looks like

```
+--------+-------+------+
| term   | lat   | lng  |
+--------+-------+------+
```

So the first query is something very simple

```
select lat, lng from my_search_table where term = "the term"
```

If I find a result, I then search with a nice method for all the vendors in the range the visitor wants and print the result on a map.

If I don't find a result, I search with a levenshtein function because people writing bruxelle or bruxeles instead of bruxelles is something really common and I don't want to make a request to google maps all the time (I also have a "how many time searched" column in my table to get some stats)

So I request my_search_time with no where clause and loop through all results to get the smallest levensthein distance. If the smallest result is greater than 2, I request coordinates from google maps.

Here is my problem. For some countries (we have several sites all around the world), my_search_table has 15-20k+ entries... and php doesn't (really) like looping on such data (which I perfectly understand) and my request falls under the php timeout. I could increase this timeout but the problem will be the same in a few months.

So I tried a levensthein MySQL function (found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617348/mysql-levenshtein) btw) but it's also very slow.

So my question is "is there any way to make this search fast even on very large datasets ?"

Comment: Although I can't help, +1 for well formatted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is based on three things:

- First, your data set is *big*. That means - it's: *big enough* to reject the idea of "select all" + "run [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/levenshtein) in PHP application"
- Second, you have control over your database. So you can adjust some architecture-related things
- Finally, performance of `SELECT` queries is the most important thing, while performance for adding new data **doesn't matter**.

The thing is **you can not** perform *fast* levenshtein search because *levenshtein itself* is very slow. I mean, calculating levenshtein distance is a slow thing. Thus, you'll not be able to resolve the issue with only "smart search". You'll have to prepare some data.

Possible solution will be: create some group index and assign it *during adding/updating* data. That means - you'll store additional column which will store some hash (numeric, for example). When adding new data, you'll:

- Perform search with levenshtein distance (for that you may either use your application or that function which you've (already mentioned) over all records in your table against inserted data
- Set group index for new row to value of index which found rows in previous step have.
- If nothing found, set some new group index value (it' the first row and there are no similar rows yet) - which will be different from any group index values that already present in table

To search desired rows, you'll need just select rows with same group index value. That means: your *select* queries will be very fast. But - yes, this will cause extremely huge overhead when adding/changing your data. Thus, it isn't applicable for case, when performance of updating/inserting matters.

Comment: +1; preparing data is often a worthy trade-off, the insert is only very little slower but the select is much faster

Answer (score 1):

You could try MySQL function [**SOUNDS LIKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like)

```
SELECT lat, lng FROM my_search_table WHERE term SOUNDS LIKE "the term"
```

Comment: The Levenshtein distance finds typos much better than using Soundex, so I doubt this will be a good solution.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't think sounds like will help me. According to the MySQL doc, it's work pretty well with english but we have a lot of "_european utf8 languages_", cyrillic, arabic and even asian languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a kd-tree or a ternary tree to speed up the search. The idea is to use a binary search.