# How to not search for exact word match using LIKE?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys I am using the following query to select data

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodcuts WHERE prod_name LIKE '%".$search."%'");
```

The problem is when you search let's say 'he' it select more than I would like. It takes 'hello' 'helblabla' everything with 'he' in it.

What I would like to do is when let's say you are searching for playstation it accepts the following searches playstatioq, yplaystation, playstationq etc.. 
So I want to allow the search to differ one letter from the exact product name. Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Check out [MySQL Levenshtein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617348/mysql-levenshtein) here on StackOverflow for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Glen Solsberry wrote, you can use an '_' (underscore) for a single letter wild card search. For example:

```
"SELECT * FROM prodcuts WHERE prod_name LIKE '%_".$search."_%'"
```

If your `$search` var is '*laystatio*', this query will match 'playstation', 'yplaystation', 'playstationq' and 'playstatioq'.

If your `$search` var is '*playstation*', or '*playstatioq*', or '*yplaystation*', using [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex), this next query should return the result you are after, plus a heap that are a close match:

```
"SELECT * FROM prodcuts WHERE SOUNDEX(prod_name) LIKE SOUNDEX('".$search."')"
```

Comment: Thank you I will use this until I understand the Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially solve your problem obliquely by building an index with something like Elastic Search or Solr that provides fuzzy matching for full text queries.

Depending on the scale of your problem, efficiency requirements, and how fuzzy you need your matches to be, it could save you a lot of effort. On the other hand, it could of course be overkill.